Problems with search index using MySQL 8 and CraftCMS 4.8.0
I have been testing our site using MySQL 8.0.36, and all seems great other than the search index seems to be not working as expected as any entry search with a string over 10 characters in length returns 0 results.
I resaved entries with --update-search-index and the problem still persist.
I was wondering if it could be something to do with the collation, so I tried converting all tables to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, but this fails with the following error:
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE craft_content CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci.
Any pointers to what my problem may be are gladly received. I'm sure it's something I'm not thinking about somewhere. Thanks!

what happens if you use utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

I had to change some fields to text to convert the content database to utf8mb4_unicode_ci, but I'm having the same issues with the search.

I'm at a loss as to what I need to change.
The following returns results
SELECT elementId
FROM craft_searchindex
WHERE (((siteId = '1')) AND MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('experience*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
If I change it to experienced i get 0 results:
SELECT elementId
FROM craft_searchindex
WHERE (((siteId = '1')) AND MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('experienced*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))

The problem was that innodb_ft_max_token_size was set to 10 in the my.ini.
Updating this and re-saving the index solved the issue. Thanks!
